# OneHotEncoding mapping issue between training data and test data

Tags: pandas, numpy, scikit-learn, one-hot-encoding

I've transformed training and test data set by sklearn OneHotEncoding method. However, trnsformed results have different type shape. So It is impossible to apply to other algorithms like logistic regression.

How do I reshape the test data in accordance with the training data set's shape?

Best Regardings, Chris

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder, LabelEncoder 

def data_transformation(data, dummy):  
    le = LabelEncoder()

    # Encoding the columns with multiple categorical levels
    for col1 in dummy:
        le.fit(data[col1])
        data[col1] = le.transform(data[col1])

    dummy_data = np.array(data[dummy])
    enc = OneHotEncoder()
    enc.fit(dummy_data)

    dummy_data = enc.transform(dummy_data).toarray() 

if __name__ == '__main__': 
    data = pd.read_csv('train.data', delimiter=',') 
    data_test = pd.read_csv('test.data', delimiter=',')

    dummy_columns = ['Column1', 'Column2'] 
    data = data_transformation(data, dummy_columns)
    data_test = data_transformation(data_test, dummy_columns)

# result 
# data shape : (200000, 71 ) 
# data_test shape : ( 15000, 32)
```

Comment: Are you sure about the indentations? I see you are making lot of edits to this post.

Comment: I finished this post..

Comment: You are fitting the OneHotEncoder() and LabelEncoder() two times: one for `data` and other for `data_test`. Thats why you are getting mismatch in shape. These encoders should only be `fit()` on train data, and only called `transform()` for test data.

Comment: Thank you so much, Vivek! I've solved this issue for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you so much, Vivek! I've solved this issue due to your help.

```
def data_transformation2(data, data_test, dummy):
    le = LabelEncoder()

    # Encoding the columns with multiple categorical levels
    for col in dummy:
        le.fit(data[col])
        data[col] = le.transform(data[col])

    for col in dummy:
        le.fit(data_test[col])
        data_test[col] = le.transform(data_test[col])

    enc = OneHotEncoder()
    dummy_data = np.array(data[dummy])
    dummy_data_test = np.array(data_test[dummy])

    enc.fit(dummy_data)

    dummy_data = enc.transform(dummy_data).toarray()
    dummy_data_test = enc.transform(dummy_data_test).toarray()

    print(dummy_data.shape)
    print(dummy_data_test.shape)
```